# error processing package dynare-matlab: post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Tags: matlab

I have installed **Matlab R2016b** on my UBUNTU 16.04 and it works perfectly. Because I need Matlab only to run DSGE models I have to install `Dynare`.

---

I followed the steps provided by Dynare developer. Once I add the APT source line in my repository it pops out this **error message** after reloading

```
W: http://www.dynare.org/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key 
5081D8000DDBD00D3FB37274CF7C7C5424FA6A8A uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

I decided to continue the installation of the following from `Synaptic`:

- `dynare`
- `dynare.dc`
- `dynare-matlab`

Stops once it starts to install the package `dynare-matlab`, giving the following **error**:

```
Setting up dynare-matlab (4.4.3-2ubuntu4) ...
Building Matlab extensions (logfile at /tmp/dynare-matlab-mexbuild-1481835320.9qi80WD)

chown: invalid user: ‘/home/daniele’
dpkg: error processing package dynare-matlab (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing: dynare-matlab
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Other posts suggest to install   `libmatio-dev`  but the newest version is already installed.

---

Comment: Seems to be a [new bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dynare/+bug/1580761). :( I suggest you log in there and select "this bug affects me", in order to raise its status and get a fix. In the mean time, why don't you try with an older version of dynare?